# Setup an HTTP Server Side Proxy or Tunnel Server

Tags: http, proxy, xampp, vagrant, tunnel

I have a Nexus 7 connected to our Wifi Network. I cannot root this device so I can't edit the hosts file. It can connect to the XAMPP Web Server on my Desktop computer.

On my Desktop computer I have a VM, configured via Vagrant and it has a Private Network so only my Desktop (Host) can access it. This VM has my development environment and Web Server running on port 8080. I can connect to this VM from my Desktop browser using only the hostname `http://nick:8080/`. I have had to edit the hosts file on my Desktop to map nick to the VM IP (192.168.33.10). `http://192.168.33.10:8080` doesn't work because of the VM's Web Server config.

So I can easily test native mobile devices, I'm trying to find a way of tunneling or proxying the requests from XAMPP (or another Server) to the VM.

My N7 can access XAMPP so I'm thinking can I set XAMPP up as a Proxy or Tunnel Server which can communicate to the VM.

N7 -> Proxy/Tunnel Server (XAMPP) -> VM.

I need the Proxy/Tunnel server to maintain the header `http://nick:8080` as `http://192.168.33.10:8080` doesn't work.

Can I do this using Apache config or is there another utility server that can help?

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: Can you provide your `Vagrantfile` so we can see how you're configuring the VM's network?  What virtualization software are you using, and what is the guest OS?  You may not need a proxy as Vagrant has some pretty good networking config abilities, especially with a Linux guest.  But really depends on the details ...

Comment: I'd like to use the Proxy approach instead of opening the VM up on the Public Network.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to achieve what you want using one of the following depending on how you are actually requesting your application:

1. If you want to map `http://nick:8080` to `http://192.168.33.10:8080` you can try adding this in your xampp apache config :

   `ProxyRemote * http://192.168.33.10:8080/`
2. If you are using a subdirectory on eg `http://nick:8080/mobile` then try:

   `ProxyPass /mobile http://192.168.33.10:8080`

   `ProxyPassReverse /mobile http://192.168.33.10:8080`
3. As an alternative you can try using a rewrite rule:

   `RewriteRule ^/mobile(.*) http://192.168.33.10:8080/mobile$1 [P]`

Comment: Hi, I've tried steps one and two above in the httpd.conf file, restarted the server but I'm getting a Server Error: 500. Perhaps I need to put them somewhere specific within the file? Thanks.

Comment: What does the apache error log say?  Have you got mod_proxy enabled? I should have mentioned this was a prerequisite for using the proxy directives.